# How to solve "NotImplementedError"

Tags: python, pytorch, convolution

I defined a three layer convolution layer(self.convs) ,the input tensor has the shape([100,10,24])

```
x_convs = self.convs(Variable(torch.from_numpy(X).type(torch.FloatTensor)))

>>Variable(torch.from_numpy(X).type(torch.FloatTensor)).shape

torch.Size([100, 10, 24])

>>self.convs

ModuleList(
  (0): ConvBlock(
    (conv): Conv1d(24, 8, kernel_size=(5,), stride=(1,), padding=(2,))
    (relu): ReLU()
    (maxpool): AdaptiveMaxPool1d(output_size=10)
    (zp): ConstantPad1d(padding=(1, 0), value=0)
  )
  (1): ConvBlock(
    (conv): Conv1d(8, 8, kernel_size=(5,), stride=(1,), padding=(2,))
    (relu): ReLU()
    (maxpool): AdaptiveMaxPool1d(output_size=10)
    (zp): ConstantPad1d(padding=(1, 0), value=0)
  )
  (2): ConvBlock(
    (conv): Conv1d(8, 8, kernel_size=(5,), stride=(1,), padding=(2,))
    (relu): ReLU()
    (maxpool): AdaptiveMaxPool1d(output_size=10)
    (zp): ConstantPad1d(padding=(1, 0), value=0)
  )
)
```

When I excuate `x_convs = self.convs(Variable(torch.from_numpy(X).type(torch.FloatTensor)))`, it gives me the error

```
    `94             registered hooks while the latter silently ignores them.

     95         """

---> 96         raise NotImplementedError`
```

The ConvBlock is defined as below

```
class ConvBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, T, in_channels, out_channels, filter_size):
        super(ConvBlock, self).__init__()
        padding = self._calc_padding(T, filter_size)
        self.conv=nn.Conv1d(in_channels, out_channels, filter_size, padding=padding)
        self.relu=nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool=nn.AdaptiveMaxPool1d(T)       
        self.zp=nn.ConstantPad1d((1, 0), 0)        
        
    def _calc_padding(self, Lin, kernel_size, stride=1, dilation=1):
        p = int(((Lin-1)*stride + 1 + dilation*(kernel_size - 1) - Lin)/2)    
        return p                                                              
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.permute(0,2,1)    
        x = self.conv(x)        
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.maxpool(x)     
        x = x.permute(0,2,1)    
        return x
```

The "forward" function has correct indent, so I cannot figure it out what is going on.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve], along with the full error message. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a `ModuleList`, which is a `list` (i.e. a list object in Python), slightly modified for being used with PyTorch.

A quick fix would be to call the `self.convs` as:

```py
x_convs = self.convs[0](Variable(torch.from_numpy(X).type(torch.FloatTensor)))

if len(self.convs) > 1:
    for conv in self.convs[1:]:
        x_convs = conv(x_convs)
```

That is, although `self.convs` is a `list`, each member of it is a `Module`. You can directly call each member of the  `self.convs`, using its index, e.g. ``self.convsan_index`.

Or, you can do it with the help of `functools` module:

```py
from functools import reduce

def apply_layer(layer_input, layer): 
    return layer(layer_input)

output_of_self_convs = reduce(apply_layer, self.convs, Variable(torch.from_numpy(X).type(torch.FloatTensor)))
```

P.S. Though, the `Variable` keyword is not used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want these 3 layers to be executed in sequence, you should use `nn.Sequential` instead of `nn.ModuleList`. `nn.ModuleList` does not implement the `forward()` method, but `nn.Sequential` does.

If you want some special behavior in the `forward()` method, you can subclass `nn.ModuleList` and override its `forward()`.